# python can't find redis

Tags: python, redis

I have encountered the following error:

```
➜  iPokeMon-Server git:(dev) sudo python server.py
Password:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 2, in <module>
    import redis
ImportError: No module named redis
```

Here are some clues:

```
➜  iPokeMon-Server git:(dev) sudo easy_install redis
Searching for redis
Best match: redis 2.8.0
Processing redis-2.8.0-py2.7.egg
redis 2.8.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis-2.8.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for redis
Finished processing dependencies for redis
```

---

```
➜  iPokeMon-Server git:(dev) sudo pip install redis
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): redis in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis-2.8.0-py2.7.egg
Cleaning up...
```

### and for the one below said

```
➜  iPokeMon-Server git:(dev) pip install redis
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): redis in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis-2.8.0-py2.7.egg
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: What is the output of `python -c "import sys; print '\n'.join(sys.path)"`?

Comment: And what is the content of `server.py`?

Comment: What shows `pip freeze --local` ? (sorry for the preivous post as an answer, i thought to post a comment... the format on the smartphone was not clear)

Comment: @Johnsyweb ➜  iPokeMon-Server git:(dev) python -c "import sys; print '\n'.join(sys.path)"                                                      )git:(dev[]

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis-2.8.0-py2.7.egg
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7

Comment: @Johnsyweb from bottle import Bottle, run, request, response
import redis
from hashlib import md5
import time
import config

server = Bottle()
RADIS_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_DB   = 8

# Request Header
class Header(object):
    def __init__(self, headers):
        self.headers = headers

Comment: @FoxMaSk redis==2.8.0

Comment: do you use a `virtualenv` named `dev` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use a virtualenv named `dev` then dont do

```
sudo pip install redis
```

but just

```
pip install redis
```

this will install the redis package in your own virtualenv instead of your "complet" system .
 And this time your redis package will be found from your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure OP may have moved past this but for users who still land here, One of the possible reasons is you've installed python3 and are trying to install the package via `pip` instead of `pip3`.

```
pip3 install redis
```

should sort this.